# CSS: Is it possible to specify a style to a fieldset before another fieldset?

Tags: html, css

CSS: Is it possible to specify a style to a fieldset before another fieldset? When Two fieldset follow in my code I would like to apply them a specific style.

EDIT Without using class and id of course...

Here is my code

```
        <div id="tabs">
            <fieldset class="one">
                <legend>One</legend>
                Text
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="two">
                <legend>Two</legend>
                Text
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Ths give me this :

[image]

And I would like this :

[image]

Comment: is it something a class cannot do ?

Comment: yes........but can't show in absence of code

Comment: Can you share some code of what you're looking at and trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS you can apply styles only to child of any element or siblings of it, that's why we can apply style only on second `fieldset` using `+` Adjacent sibling selector. In following demo i will show how to do it.

About all possible **CSS2 selector** you can read in [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) to make yourself understand: what you can made with css selector and what not

May be my explanation [**demo on dabblet.com**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2924668) can help you to solve your problem.

**The result:**
[image]

**HTML markup:**

```
<fieldset> </fieldset>
<fieldset> </fieldset>
<fieldset> </fieldset>
<fieldset> </fieldset>
```

**CSS markup:**

```
/* detect only first fieldset */
fieldset:first-child {
    background-color: green;
}

/* detect all sibling fieldset element after first one */
fieldset:first-child ~ fieldset {
    background-color: gray; 
}

/* detect only first sibling fieldset element after first one */
fieldset:first-child + fieldset {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any classes or id's you can use `first-child` to target the first one and then use the default styling for second.

e.g.

```
form fieldset{ background: green; }
form fieldset:first-child{ background: red; }
```

First fieldset will have a red background, any others will have a green background. Note though this is for fieldsets within the same form. If they are in separate forms, then you can apply the same principle using the `form:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign each one a specific class or ID?

```
<fieldset class="firstset"></fieldset>
<fieldset class="secondset"></fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using ID or class names , then go for the first-child property.

For eg -

```
form fieldset:first-child{
  //your css code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use classes or id's but still want them to have different styles, how about using inline CSS for each fieldset?

Is there a particularly good reason to avoid classes and id's while still wanting to use CSS?  With a little more detail, we can probably give you a better answer.